# Disk Usage Utility Daily Stats Tool [Gui]

Tags: kubuntu, gui, disk-usage, process, disk-utility

I have seen a lot of posts regarding my Issue ,but no one has satisfactory answer specially in regard of daily disk usage by different processes
I want a complete disk usage monitoring tool ,which will provide:-

1. **Daily /Monthly Disk usage** by OS along with  processes Report.
2. Active Disk usage as per process ,which is available by 'iostat ; sar; dstat' but i want **GUI** (*ksar* no longer maintained by author and not working on my system.).

All i got what is diskstats which provide whooping 20gb write on my `/` disk just browsing packages and installing 1-5 mb packages.

I am using **SSD** and that's why i am bothering about it.

I have also tried **ksysload** by kde  but that has only same active Disk I/O Graph only plug.

Comment: how about  `iostat ; sar; dstat` piped into a CSV file and opened by OpenOffice Calc?

Comment: @Fabby requires the installation of `sysstat` and `dstat`.